# Filter many to many field in Django model

Tags: python, django

I have these 2 models in a Django app:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
   name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

In my views, I'd like to **filter the articles and only get the articles where `articles.tags` contains the tag with `id == 2`**. How can I do that ?

I tried

`tags = Tag.objects.filter(pk=2);`

`articles = Article.objects.filter(len(tags) > 0)` but I have this error `'bool' object is not itterable`.

Answer (score 16):

This is the correct way of filtering manytomany in django

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(tags__in=[2])
```

or

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(pk=2)
articles = Article.objects.filter(tags__in=tags)
```

Comment: There is only one tag with id `2` so it is better to use `tag = Tag.objects.get(pk=2) ` which returns a `Tag` instance instead of a `QuerySet`, you can then use `tag.article_set.all()`

Comment: @aumo :  If he knows the id of tag, then no need to call reverse relation, he can directly use the solution which i provided first

Comment: That is true, I was commenting on your second solution, as for your first, it would make more sense to use `Article.objects.filter(tags__id=2)`

Comment: What if if have the `tag.name` and not the `id` ?

Comment: @rocketer it is the same logic `tags__name`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(tags__id=2)
```

or, if you need to retrieve the `Tag` instance too,

```
tag = Tag.objects.get(id=2)
articles = tag.article_set.all()
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this way:-**

```
var = Tag.objects.all().values('name','tags__title')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29893744)